# Group by ids, sort by date and get values as list on big data python

Tags: python, group-by, bigdata, pandas-groupby

I have a big data (30 milions rows).
Each table has id,date,value.
I need to go over each id and per these id get a list of values sorted by date so the first value is the list will be the older date.

Example:

```
ID     DATE     VALUE
1   02/03/2020   300
1   04/03/2020   200
2   04/03/2020   456
2   01/03/2020   300
2   05/03/2020   78
```

Desire table:

```
ID     VALUE_LIST_ORDERED     
1      [300,200]
2      [300,456,78]
```

I can do it by for loop, by apply but its not effictive and with milion of users it's not feasible.
I thought about using group by and sort the dates but I dont know of to make a list and if so, groupby on pandas df is the best way?

I would love to get some suggestions on how to do it and which kind of df/technology to use.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do is to order your data using [pandas.dataframe.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and then apply the groupby method

I don't have huge data set to test this code on, but I believe this would do the trick:

```
sorted = data.sort_values('DATE')
result = data.groupby('ID').VALUE.apply(np.array)
```

and since it's Python you can always put everything in one statement

```
print(data.sort_values('DATE').data.groupby('ID').VALUE.apply(np.array))
```

Comment: Thank you! I am going to check it on the whole data.